# Can fluid catalytic cracking work on a smaller scale in a laboratory?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, catalysis, hydrocarbons

[Fluid Catalytic Cracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_catalytic_cracking) usually requires a very large and tall structure. Is there a way of miniaturizing the process to fit inside a chemical lab with 10 ft ceilings? Specifically: can a fluidized bed reactor operate on this scale?

Comment: I guess there are probably such pilot reactors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_plant